# C file reading doesn't read an array of numbers in as string

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

None of fgets() and fscanf() works, the file.txt has

```
100
6 0060001
6 4321298
3 5001
6 0604008
6 0102111
```

My code reads the first integer pretty well but the not the 7 digit number? Any help?

```
int main(void)
{
    int numTotal = 0;
    int maxShy = 0;
    char temp[101];
    char ch;
    char * ptr;
    int count = 0;

    FILE *fp1 = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("output", "w");

    // read the first line, set the total number
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != '\n')
    {
        temp[count] = ch;
        count++;
    }
    temp[++count] = '\0';
    count = 0;
    numTotal = strtol(temp, &ptr, 10);
    printf("%d", numTotal);


    for (int i = 0; i < numTotal; i++)
    {
        // This part works fine
        fscanf(fp1, "%d", &maxShy);
        printf("%d ", maxShy);

        // This part doesn't outputs a different 7 digit number from 0060001 and others
        fscanf(fp1, "%s", temp);
        printf("%s\n", temp);
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the output ??

Comment: this line: 'temp[++count] = '\0';' leaves a garbage character before the '\0' byte.  suggest removing the '++'

Comment: this line: 'fscanf(fp1, "%s", temp);' will read nothing as the input will contain a space character.  suggest: 'fscanf(fp1, " %s", temp);'  Note the leading space in the format string.  a space in a format string will skip over white space, like the space between the two values

Comment: The out put was Assertion Failure, and something to do with the String.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
temp[++count] = '\0';
```

you need

```
temp[count] = '\0';
```

since you are incrementing `count` in the `while` loop.

Also, the first line indicates that `100` lines of text are expected. However, you only have `6` more lines of text. Nothing is read after that. Add checks to make sure that you stop when reading fails.

Instead of:

```
fscanf(fp1, "%d", &maxShy);
```

Use

```
if ( fscanf(fp1, "%d", &maxShy) != 1 )
{
   break;
}
```

Similarly, use:

```
if ( fscanf(fp1, "%s", temp) != 1 )
{
   break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, also I only pasted the first 6 lines of the text file. I should try to change the count.